# How do i make docker container resources mutually exclusive?

Tags: docker, containers

I want multiple running containers to have mutually exclusive resources with each other. For example, when there are CPU cores from id0 to id63, if 32 CPU cores are allocated to each container, the CPU cores assigned to them are mutually exclusive. In addition, when the host has 16GB of RAM, we want to allocate 8GB to each container so that one container does not affect the memory usage of another container.

Is there good way to do this?

Comment: IMO, most people with this requirement haven't thought it through. You can do this, but it isn't a mainstream use-case for containers. The main reason is that if one service is idle, you'll be wasting half of your machine. If the other service has exhausted all of its resources it won't have access to the resources belonging to the idle service.

Comment: If you're in a cloud environment, you could accomplish this by getting two separate instances of half the size.  Docker doesn't really do this.

Answer (score -1):

I think all you need is to just limit container resources. This way you can ensure that no container uses more than X cores and/or Y RAM. To limit CPU usage to 1 core add `--cpus=1.0` to your `docker run` command. To limit RAM to 8 gigabytes add `-m=8g`. Putting it altogether:

```
docker run --rm --cpus=1 -m=8g debian:buster cat /dev/stdout
```

And if your look at `docker stats` you will see that memory is limited (no indication for CPU though):

```
CONTAINER ID        NAME                CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %               NET I/O             BLOCK I/O           PIDS
8d9a33b00950        funny_shirley       0.00%               1MiB / 8GiB           0.10%               6.7kB / 0B          0B / 0B             1
```

Read more in the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/).